# Define and call Javascript function in XSLT

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

I want to define a function in a XSL file, and use it to valorize a page attribute in the XSL.
I defined the function as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:jsutil="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="no" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <![CDATA[   
        ...
        function replaceTokenUrlCustomerInfo(url) {
          ...
          var server_url; 
          ...
          return server_url;
        }
```

And in my XSL i call the function in this way:

```
 ...
<xsl:element name="iframe">
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
   javascript:replaceTokenUrlCustomerInfo('<xsl:value-of select="DESC_URL"/>'); 
</xsl:attribute>
```

But the function isn't called, in the browser console I see error

> ReferenceError: replaceTokenUrlCustomerInfo is not defined

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks
I have another question: can I set the src attribute via Javascript function? I have experience only for onclick attributes

Comment: It is not clear in which context you use XSLT, which version of XSLT you use, which XSLT processor, but the first snippet seems to show an HTML `script` element which has nothing to do with XSLT, other than HTML being one of the target formats of XSLT. And what is the context of that `xsl:attribute`, is that also an HTML element? Does your approach to call Javascript in the `src` attribute (of which element?) work in a normal HTML document (i.e. one not generated by XSLT)? Consider to show minimal but complete samples to allow others to understand and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect to happen? You want to create an HTML `iframe` element with a `src` attribute, how should the value of the `src` attribute look, given a certain value of the `DESC_URL` element you seem to have in your XML? Which XSLT processor do you use? Do you expect the XSLT processor to execute the script or the browser to execute the script?

Comment: If you are expecting XSLT to execute the script to get the URL, then it might be worth explaining exactly what the function is trying to do. It may be you don't need javascript at all here (especially if you can use XSLT 2.0, as the version number suggests). Thanks!

Comment: I solved in another way, I tried to call the function to valorize the attribute src, the function replaceTokenUrlCustomerInfo would have taken a URL and replaced some placeholders in it with the effective values of the parameters, and return the URL with the placeholders replaced. But after some attempts, I moved the function in the jquery script associated with the page